# Ipad multi network chat and SMS app

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, sms, chat

Is there an ipad app for various Instant message networks and SMS? Please recommend something that's as minimalist as the iMessage app, not a big flashy mess.

Answer (score 1):

There is no app that can manage SMS/MMS as well as your other instant messaging networks. You will need to use Messages app for iMessage & SMS/MMS, and a third-party app for any other IM networks (such as AOL, Google Talk, Yahoo!, etc.).